# Load classes dynamically in TypeScript without default export

Tags: typescript

I am trying to load classes in TypeScript dynamically, I got it to work partially but I was wondering if I can make it work without a default export:

```js
export default class Test extends Base {
...
register(new (await import(file)).default())
```

edit: thanks to Dhananjai's answer I found this solution:
(parse is coming from path and I am using glob to get all paths to files in a directory)

```js
for (const file of files) {
  try {
    const { name } = parse(file)
    const command = new (await import(file))[name]()
    this.register(command)
  } catch {
    return logger.error(`${file} is either not exporting a class or the file name does not match the exported class name`)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as

```
export class Test extends Base
...
register(new (await import(file)).Test())
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to post the code I am using to loop over files, "file" is a path to a file like `/general/Test.ts`, the "Test" part is dynamic so I am not sure how I can get that part to make the above work in a loop

Comment: update the question, with your specific scenario, explaining all the parts

Comment: I have added the solution, thank you for showing me the .Test() part, I would love to know if this can be improved since I now rely on the file name having the same name as the class instead of getting the class name dynamically